# WPF '*' character not spacing correctly

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a `ListBox` in a Windows Universal App and each `ListBoxItem` is a `Grid` with columns of varying text and images. For some `ColumnDefinitions` I have specific widths and then I am trying to distribute the remaining space evenly among the remaining columns. As I understand it the `*` character will do that but instead seems to be behaving more like `Auto` and allocating only the necessary amount of space.

So instead of `foo   bar   baz` I am getting `foobarbaz`.

Does anyone might know what I am doing wrong?

```
<ListBox x:Name="ItemsListBox" Grid.Row="3"  Margin="0, 80, 0, 80" VerticalAlignment="Top" ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" Loaded="ItemsListBox_Loaded">
    <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" />
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Grid x:Name="ItemsListBoxGrid">
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="60" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="150" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="45" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="100" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <Image Grid.Column="0" Height="40" Source="{Binding Img}" />
                <TextBlock Grid.Column="1"  Text="{Binding Name}" />
                <TextBlock Grid.Column="2" Text="{Binding Level}" />
                <TextBlock Grid.Column="3" Text="{Binding Rarity}" />
                <TextBlock Grid.Column="4" Text="{Binding Type}" />
                <TextBlock Grid.Column="5" Text="{Binding MinSaleOffer}" />
                <TextBlock Grid.Column="6" Text="{Binding MaxBuyOffer}" />
                <TextBlock Grid.Column="7" Text="{Binding Margin}" />
                <TextBlock Grid.Column="8" Text="{Binding Supply}" />
                <TextBlock Grid.Column="9" Text="{Binding Demand}" />
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't do anything wrong, it's just the default container (ListBoxItem) style that aligns content to the left thus preventing your Grid to Measure/Arrange.
Just add the following to your ListBox.

```
<ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
     <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
          <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
          <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
     </Style>
</ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
```

Answer (score 2):

The default style for `ListBox` sets it's `HorizontalContentAlignment` property to `Left`, which in turn causes all your visuals to be left-aligned, instead of stretching to the available space. Therefore, the "remaining space" you're looking for is effectively zero.

Use:

```
<ListBox HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch">`
    <!-- etc ... -->
</ListBox>
```

Comment: Sorry, didn't saw your answer before I posted.